# how do I skip the first line when writing to a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

So I'm using 2 methods to write to a CSV file, both using a PrintWriter and StringBuilder.

Method one only writes the subject of the CSV file, that is, it writes something into the first line of the CSV file.

The second method writes some other data I need into the rest of the same CSV file.

My question is what I can do to skip the first line of the CSV file, so that when I write into it in my second method, I don't end up overwriting what I wrote in the first method.

---

```
public void writeData(String filename, ArrayList<ITemperature> theWeatherList) {
    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename)){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < theWeatherList.size(); i++) {
            // Appends current ITemperature object to string builder
            String[] temp = asString(theWeatherList.get(i)).split(",");
            sb.append(temp[0]);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(temp[1]);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(temp[2]);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(temp[3]);
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(temp[4]);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        // Writes into file
        pw.write(sb.toString());
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Data written to file.");
```

### }

Comment: Can you add a working sample of your code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are writing your output CSV file? When writing a file in general, you can setup the `append` option, instead of always creating a new file, that maybe is your case, but just tricking you, so you think it is overwriting the 1st line of your output file.

Comment: i added the method that writes the data to my file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your code, but try to do it.

```
fw = new FileWriter("file.csv", true); 
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
pw = new PrintWriter(bw); 
pw.println("Line one"); 
pw.println("Line two"); 
pw.println("Line three");
```